# How to stop all sounds and animations from playing at once in simple Android Game?

Tags: java, android

I am working through the book Learning Java by Building Android Games by John Horton.

[Link to book Java by Building Android Games by John Horton](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/learning-java-building-android-games)

It's a pretty good book and I'm working through it typing in the games. I've got a memory game working which plays sounds from one of four buttons in a sequence that gradually increases in length (by one each turn).

The problem I have with my code is that the buttons vibrate and make a sound at what appears to be the same time to me as a user.

How can I add a delay to stop everything happening at once? The first sequence is only one button so it will only vibrate and sound one button - so no confusion there.

The screen shot is what it should look like for every button vibration of the sequence.

I've tried :

```
     ...
     case 1:
     //play a sound
     button1.startAnimation(wobble);
     soundPool.play(sample1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

try {
 wait(1000);
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Unable to wait");
}
    break;
...
```

For each button/case statement - but it does not work.

[image: Memory Game - Game Screen with buttons]

```
package com.packtpub.memorygame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //phase 5 - our animation object
    Animation wobble;

    //prepare objects and sound references

    //initalize sound variables
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    int sample1 = -1;
    int sample2 = -1;
    int sample3 = -1;
    int sample4 = -1;

    //for our UI
    TextView textScore;
    TextView textDifficutly;
    TextView textWatchGo;

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button buttonReplay;

    //Some variables for our Thread
    int difficultyLevel = 3;
    //An Array to hold the randomly generated sequence
    int[] sequenceToCopy = new int[100];

    private Handler myHandler;
    //Are we playing a sequence at the moment?
    boolean playSequence = false;
    //And which element of the sequence are we on?
    int elementToPlay = 0;

    //For checking the players answer
    int playerResponses;
    int playerScore;
    boolean isResponding;

    //for our hiscore (Phase 4)
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String dataName = "MyData";
    String intName = "MyString";
    int defaultInt = 0;
    int hiScore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //phase 5 animation
        wobble = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wobble);

        //phae 4
        //initialize our two SharedPreferences objects
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(dataName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        hiScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);


        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        try {

            //Create objects of the 2 required classes
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

            //Create our three fx in memory ready for use
            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sample1.ogg");
            sample1 = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sample2.ogg");
            sample2 = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sample3.ogg");
            sample3 = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sample4.ogg");
            sample4 = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            //First the TextViews
            textScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
            textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
            textDifficutly = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDifficulty);

            textDifficutly.setText("Level: " + difficultyLevel);
            textWatchGo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textWatchGo);

            //Now the buttons
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            buttonReplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReplay);
            //Now set all the buttons to listen for clicks
            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);
            button4.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonReplay.setOnClickListener(this);

            //This is the code which will define our thread
            myHandler = new Handler() {

                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    super.handleMessage(msg);

                    if (playSequence) {


                        //All the thread action will go here
//                        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        switch (sequenceToCopy[elementToPlay]) {

                            case 1:
                                //hide a button
//                                button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //play a sound
                                button1.startAnimation(wobble);
                                soundPool.play(sample1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                break;

                            case 2:
//                                button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //play a sound
                                button2.startAnimation(wobble);
                                soundPool.play(sample2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                break;

                            case 3:

//                                button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //play a sound
                                button3.startAnimation(wobble);
                                soundPool.play(sample3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                //hide a button
//                                button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //play a sound
                                button4.startAnimation(wobble);
                                soundPool.play(sample4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                break;
                        }

                        elementToPlay++;
                        if (elementToPlay == difficultyLevel) {

                            sequenceFinished();
                            myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 900);

                        }
                    }
                    myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 900);


                }


            };//end of thread

            myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //catch exceptions here
        }
        playASequence();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!playSequence) {//only accept input if sequence not playing

            switch (v.getId()) {
                //case statements...
                case R.id.button:
                    //play a sound
                    soundPool.play(sample1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    checkElement(1);
                    break;

                case R.id.button2:
                    //play a sound
                    soundPool.play(sample2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    checkElement(2);
                    break;

                case R.id.button3:
                    //play a sound
                    soundPool.play(sample3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    checkElement(3);
                    break;

                case R.id.button4:
                    //play a sound
                    soundPool.play(sample4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    checkElement(4);
                    break;

                case R.id.buttonReplay:
                    difficultyLevel = 3;
                    playerScore = 0;
                    textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
                    playASequence();
                    break;
            }


        }

    }

    public void createSequence() {

        Log.i("info:", "current high score is: " + hiScore);

        //For choosing a random button
        Random randInt = new Random();
        int ourRandom;


        for (int i = 0; i < difficultyLevel; i++) {
            //Get a random number between 1 and 4
            ourRandom = randInt.nextInt(4);
            ourRandom++;

            //save that number to our array
            sequenceToCopy[i] = ourRandom;


            Log.i("info", "Random Number" + ourRandom);


        }
    }

    public void playASequence() {
        createSequence();
        isResponding = false;
        elementToPlay = 0;
        playerResponses = 0;
        textWatchGo.setText("WATCH!");
        playSequence = true;

    }

    public void sequenceFinished() {

        playSequence = false;
        //make sure all the buttons are made visible
//        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textWatchGo.setText("Go!");
        isResponding = true;


    }

    public void checkElement(int thisElement) {
        if (isResponding) {

            Log.i("info", "this element being checked is: " + thisElement);

            playerResponses++;
            Log.i("info", "Player repsonses" + playerResponses);
            Log.i("info", "sequence to copy" + Arrays.toString(sequenceToCopy));

            if (sequenceToCopy[playerResponses - 1] == thisElement) {//Correct

                //check whether reaches this part
                Log.i("info", "Correct element!!!");

                playerScore = playerScore + ((thisElement + 1) * 2);
                textScore.setText("Score: " + playerScore);
                ;

// Log.i("info","The difficulty level is: "+difficultyLevel);
                if (playerResponses == difficultyLevel) {//got the whole sequence
                    //don't check anymore
                    Log.i("info", "All elements right!!!");
                    isResponding = false;
                    //Now raise the difficulty
                    difficultyLevel++;
                    //and play another sequence
                    playASequence();


                }
            } else {//wrong answer
                textWatchGo.setText("Failed!");
                //don't checkElement anymore
                isResponding = false;

                Log.i("info", "New high score of: " + playerScore);
                Log.i("info", "The hiScore was: " + hiScore);

                //for our high score
                if (playerScore > hiScore) {

                    hiScore = playerScore;
                    editor.putInt(intName, hiScore);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Hi-Score", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }


        }


    }
}
```

I've tried your suggestion, implemented as below and it does not give the desired result. I even get the message "The Application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

```
case 1:
                            //hide a button
                            button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //play a sound
                            button1.startAnimation(wobble);
                            soundPool.play(sample1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                            try {
                                Log.i("info","trying to wait");
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                System.out.println("Could not wait");

                            }
                            break;
```

I've tested for my own benefit that I am in the main thread as you say:-

```
if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())
```

gives "true"

Latest attempt. Still in main thread but Thread.sleep(milliseconds) now before play.Still does not properly pause between button animations and sounds. Nothing happens then two or three at once.

```
 case 1:
                            //hide a button
                           button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            //play a sound
                            try {
                                if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper())

                                                                    {
                               System.out.println("In main thread!!");
                                    // Current Thread is Main Thread.
                                }
                                Log.i("info","trying to wait");
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                System.out.println("Could not wait");

                            }
                            button1.startAnimation(wobble);
                            soundPool.play(sample1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

                            break;
```

I've tried

```
button1.wait(3000) ;
```

In a try catch block. This does not work either. Two buttons will animate at once.

Comment: are you searching for `Thread.sleep(millisecomds)`? Because that would be how you "pause" your program.

Comment: I've tried Thread.sleep(milliseconds) as edited into my question above. It did not produced the desired result. Even got "I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: The sleep needs to be before the play and not after, because every click is handled asynchronous. And the SoundPool sadly does not notify when a sound stopped. AND you can never put a sleep in the main thread or Android will raise a ANR. You need to handle this behavior in an separated thread.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers on how to put my code in a separate thread?  if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) gives in main thread "true" as you suggest. I've followed the book's program but I'm not sure how to take it to the next level.

Comment: Maybe there is a function button1.waitForAnimation() or something in this format, that blocks until the animation is done.

Comment: No button1.wait(3000) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The SoundPool `play()` method returns immediately, and the sound plays asynchronously.  If it didn't, you wouldn't be able to call it from the main UI thread, because that thread needs to be ready to handle messages from the app framework at all times.

Sleeping on the main thread has bad effects (such as the Choreographer complaint) for the same reason.  If you sleep for long enough the system will put up an "application not responding" dialog, for the simple reason that your application is not responding (it's sleeping).

The simplest way to deal with this is to send yourself a delayed message, using one of the timed message functions like [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)).  That will execute a Runnable on the current thread after a specified delay.  Post one for each future event.

You could use a separate thread to drive the timing, but since your UI is based on View elements you'll be passing messages back and forth between threads, and the complexity isn't necessary for a simple "do X after a short delay".